# Can't resolve 'react' when running "npm run"

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-mix, npm-run

My project has recently started complaining that it can't resolve react when I run the npm run dev script, which is:
cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

It seems like npm can't find the node_modules directory?

It runs fine on my windows machine, but when I upload it to the Ubuntu server I get errors.
I've tried various things, like deleting node_modules and the lock file, cleaning the npm cache, checked $NODE_PATH, reinstalled nodejs and npm to no avail.
I can't figure out if this is a path issue or I'm missing something on the server or what.

I'd appreciate any tips you have.

My package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "name": "Write.nogetdigitalt.dk",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "moment": "^2.23.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "react": "^16.5.2",
        "react-datepicker": "^2.0.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.5.0",
        "react-icons": "^3.2.0"
    }
}
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const webpack = require('webpack');

mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', 'jsx'],
        alias: {
            'react': 'React'
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'React': 'react',
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
        })
    ]
})
.disableNotifications()

.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sourceMaps()
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Error messages:

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/pages/Note/Note.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/var/www/html/write.nogetdigitalt.dk/resources/js/pages/Note'
resolve 'react' in '/var/www/html/write.nogetdigitalt.dk/resources/js/pages/Note'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /var/www/html/write.nogetdigitalt.dk/package.json (relative path: ./resources/js/pages/Note)
    aliased with mapping 'react': 'React' to 'React'
      Parsed request is a module
      using description file: /var/www/html/write.nogetdigitalt.dk/package.json (relative path: ./resources/js/pages/Note)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      after using description file: /var/www/html/write.nogetdigitalt.dk/package.json (relative path: ./resources/js/pages/Note)
        resolve as module
          /var/www/html/write.nogetdigitalt.dk/resources/js/pages/Note/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
          /var/www/html/write.nogetdigitalt.dk/resources/js/pages/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
          /var/www/html/write.nogetdigitalt.dk/resources/js/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
          /var/www/html/write.nogetdigitalt.dk/resources/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
          /var/www/html/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
          /var/www/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
          /var/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
          /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install` on your remote server?

Comment: @Jerodev I did, yes

Comment: Do you need that alias in your resolver for your project? You should try using `path.resolve(__dirname, 'path_to_folder')` instead of 'React'

Comment: @Miguel Castillo - That was it! If you post an answer I'll accept it. Thank you very much! That was quite a headace for me. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else getting this kind of problems, for path definition between different OS is better to use `path` from NodeJS

```
`const path = require('path');
[...]
resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', 'jsx'],
        alias: {
            'react': path.resolve(__dirname, 'Path to your folder to alias')
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have installed package dependencies.

```
npm install
```

After execute that node-module directorie has created.
And launch your application.

```
npm run developement
```

Comment: Yes, I have. Everything is installed. I've even deleted everything a couple times, and reran npm install. I think it's just unable to find node_modules maybe?

Comment: Remove node_modules and re install

Comment: I wrote, several times, that I did that already. The problem was my webpack configuration.